# yii2 groupBy and count each group

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

Is there a way to do something like this

```
Model::find()->groupBy('type')->count();
```

and get count of models for each type, for example

```
 [1]=>14,
 [2]=>22,
 [3]=>123
```

Comment: can you add your raw `MYSQL` query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
$results = Model::find()
->select('count(*) as counters, type')
->groupBy('type')
->createCommand()
->queryAll();
```